# How to enter "carriage return" in Android Google Keep in checkbox view?

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to add a new line in checkbox note items in Google Keep app using Android Keyboard (AOSP); but instead, a new checkbox item is added when I do :

- double tap on shift key → enter
- drag from shift key to enter
- long press enter key

I can accomplish the purpose nicely in PC (Google Keep Chrome Extension) with Shift+Enter combination; but how to in Android !?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible at the moment.
Only thing I can think of is to use a clipboard app and copy-paste a soft linebreak into Google keep.

Answer (score -2):

Android (AOSP) keyboard:
When you hit the shift key (the one for the capital letters), automatically the key for the smiley (that is at the bottom right) becomes the key to start a new line.

SwiftKey Keyboard: (when keyboard of the letters (alphabetical)).
 (from the keyboard of the letters .(a b c ..) simply hold for a moment the key for the smiley, at the bottom right.

Comment: This will enter a new item, not a soft linebreak.